# C++ reading and writing problems in using std::vector with classes

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

I have this class in a hpp file:

```
class info
{
    public:
        float lux[100];
        float pwm[100];
        float time[100];
        float ref_lux;
        int counter_samples_stream;
};
```

In the cpp file that contains this header, I create a vector of this class and because I put it in the beginning of the cpp file it is a global variable. This is the code I use to create it:

```
std::vector <info*> vect_node[3]; //creates 3 instances of class info in a vector
```

Inside the function(called abc) we are changing and initializing the vector's data by doing per example this: `vect_node[1].lux[0] = 25;` .

We are also trying to access the vector's data in another function(called zys) but when trying to access it the program crashes and returns core dumped.

Neither function abc or zys pass the vect_node in its arguments. The doubt is how can I write in `vec_node`in a function in a way it changes its values permanently(and not only in the function) and read from this vector now updated in another function(syz).

Comment: I believe the syntax `std::vector<info*> vect_node[3];` will create an array of 3 `vector`s, in the same way that `int my_array[3];` declares an array of 3 `int`s.

Comment: This `vect_node[1].lux[0] = 25;` is wrong by the way

Comment: If you want to use std::vector's constructor you have to do (3). But your pointers will still be unitialized

Comment: @Michoumichmich how do I do it then? Is it vect_node[1]->lux[0]=20``?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe you could do a `std::vector<info> vect_node(3)` which will create a vector of size 3*sizeof(info) and then use a (smart)pointer to that vector instead. Using raw pointers can be dangerous as soon as you have a destructor that, well, calls delete on the pointers and you forget to create copy and assignment constructors see [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: No, see Shane's answer, here you have an array of vectors of pointers so you have to do  `vect_node[1][i]->lux[0]=25`

Comment: Ok then if I do this `std::vector<info> vect_node(3)`, I can use write like this `vect_node[0]->lux[0]=25` and this value changes "forever"?

Comment: With `std::vector<info> vect_node(3)` you just do `vect_node[0].lux[0]=25` and its changed, yes^^

Comment: `std::vector <info*> vect_node[3]; //creates 3 instances of class info in a vector`". That can't possibly be. Your vector is a vector of `info *`. So it cannot contain an instance of class `info`, only pointers to such instances. Your code never creates any pointers to instances of class `info`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `std::vector<info*> vect_node[3];` will create an array of 3 `std::vector`s, in the same way that `int my_array[3];` declares an array of 3 `int`s.

If you want to create a single `std::vector` with an initial capacity of 3, use the fill constructor. For example,

```cpp
std::vector<info*> vect_node{3, nullptr};
```

will construct a `std::vector` called `vect_node` with an initial capacity of 3, where every element in the vector is of type `info*` has the initial value `nullptr`.

As pointed out in the comments, if you do not want a vector of pointers, you can instead use

```cpp
std::vector<info> vect_node{3};
```

In this case, a `std::vector` of size 3 will be created called `vect_node`. Each element of the vector will contain an `info` object. Using this approach, your

```
vect_node[1].lux[0] = 25;
```

will now be valid.

---

Documentation for the `std::vector` constructors can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Comment: Also should be clarified that `vector` type is `info` **pointer** not `info`, so `vect_node[1].lux[0] = 25;` will cause `reading access violation`. And aside from need to initialize elements (in this case by `new`) it can be accessed by `-> operator`.

Comment: And if I do this```std::vector<info> vect_node{3, nullptr}```? Is it correct and I can access like this ``` vect_node[1].lux[0]=20```?

Comment: With `std::vector<info> vect_node{3, nullptr}` you don't use nullptr as you don't have pointers. Just do `std::vector<info> vect_node(3)` and your way of accessing is going to be right

Comment: std::vector calls implicitly the constructor of your class

Answer (score 1):

One way to easily initialise your vector of pointers is to use smart pointers so in one line you can do:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info>> vect_node(3, std::make_shared<info>());
```

Which will create a vector of three smart pointers and allocate the memory. You will then be able to just discard the vector without much worrying. You can modify elements with `vect_node[O]->lux[0] = 10;`

You just need to create a constructor for your class `info`.